# VBA Change Date Format

Tags: excel, vba, date

I have a problem with data import. I am using the following code to import data from another CSV.

```vb
Sub Import(ByVal sFileName As String)
    Dim wb1 As Workbook
    Dim wb2 As Workbook
    Dim Sheet As Worksheet
    Dim PasteStart As Range

    Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
    Set PasteStart = [DATA!A1]

    'Clean Data Sheet
    Sheets("DATA").Select
    Cells.Select
    Selection.ClearContents

    If IsEmpty(sFileName) Then
        MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
        Exit Sub
    Else
        Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=sFileName, Delimiter:=";")

        For Each Sheet In wb2.Sheets
            With Sheet.UsedRange
                .Copy PasteStart
                Set PasteStart = PasteStart.Offset(.Rows.Count)
            End With
        Next Sheet
    End If

    wb2.Close

    'Text to Column if needed
    Call TextToColumnSemiToComa

    'Activate Home Sheet
    Worksheets("Netherland DCA").Activate

    'Complete message
    MsgBox ("Data Import Complete") 
End Sub
```

The problem is that the macro changes dates. For ex. the original file has 12/10/2019(dd/mm/yyyy), but after import its 10/12/2019(dd/mm/yyyy). Do you know where could be problem?

Comment: What is the date format set in your regional settings?

Comment: @GSerg DD/mm/yyyy

Comment: Ok the problem was with regional settings and deliminator. All fix.